# nomenclature concerning inverse maps

Tags: definition

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets with map $\psi: X \to Y$.
If $\psi$ is bijective, then the inverse map $\psi^{-1}: Y \to X$ exists.

Denote $2^X$ and $2^Y$ as power sets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

For any map $\psi: X \to Y$ we can always define the map $\varphi: 2^Y \to 2^X$ via $W \mapsto \{x \in X: \psi(x) \in W\}$.

Now my **question**: How ist $\varphi$ called?

I have found in the literature also  *inverse map* for $\varphi$ but this collides with $\psi^{-1}$.

Do you have suggestions? Thank you for your time and thoughts!

Comment: The $\varphi$ you define above can be called inverse image mapping (for example here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Inverse_Image_Mapping/Mapping)

Comment: Great! Thank you: this will do nicely. If you transfer your comment to an answer I will accept it gladly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\psi : X \to Y$, the map $\varphi : 2^Y \to 2^X$ that that sends a set in $2^Y$ to its inverse image (or preimage) in $2^X$, that is
$$ \varphi : W \mapsto \{x \in X \; : \; \psi(x) \in W\}$$
is usually called the *inverse image* (or *preimage*) *mapping* of $\psi$ (see for example [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Inverse_Image_Mapping/Mapping)).

Comment: Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Glad I could help